# Многоуровневая база данных MySQL

Tags: mysql

Нужна многоуровневая БД - 4 уровня. Т.е. для хранения меню. Будет 4 таблицы. Первый уровень - уровень доступа (admin, user, company, internet). Каждому из значений соответствуют некоторые параметры из следующей таблицы, т.е. первая таблица связана со следующей отношением "один ко многим". Допустим поле юзер содержит уровни "Авто" и "Мото". Далее "Авто" может содержать, например, "Цвет" и "Форма", т.е. это снова следующий уровень. И последний, "Цвет" содержит "Желтый" и "Зеленый", а "Форма" содежит значение "Легковой". Это выглядит как 4-уровневое дерево. Не очень понимаю как в запросе на создание таблиц это указать - отношения один ко многим. Делал только визуальном редакторе.

П.С. Каюсь. Знаю: "читай книжки". Просто нет времени. Нужно срочно сделать.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Из вопроса нифига не понятно!

Многоуровневая БД это что вообще такое? БД в которой есть более одной таблицы?

Comment: Этот вопрос уже второй раз. @Андрей Бакша упорно спрашивает, но упорно не желает объяснить, что же ему надо. Учтите, Ваша терминология другим может быть непонятна -- не все же учатся на Вашем курсе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну во-первых выкинте из головы словосочетание "многоуровневая БД".
Далее - у вас стандартная ситуация - отношения между таблицами по определенному полю (полям) - на то БД и называются реляционными. Как делыть связь-  тут 2 подхода:

1. Используем формат таблиц InnoDB -
       тут можно указать внешние ключи
       отношений. При етом вся логика  на
       возможность добавления, удаления и
       обновления записи  будет лежать на
       СУБД.
2. Используем формат таблиц MyISAM -
       тут внешних ключей непредусмотерно.
       ПОэтому вся логика 
           на возможность добавления, удаления
           и обновления - ложится на
           разработчика приложения работающего
           с данной БД.

Для того чтобы выбрать - сначала изучите формат таблиц их преимущества и недостатки - на поверхностное изучение  (что хватит в вашем случае) уйдет не более часа

Comment: @Ale_x Спасибо.Видимо без мат.части не обойтись...

Answer (score 0):

Алиасы в помощь, наверное. :)